# What is the exercise called that works your and inner thighs while on your back?

Tags: cardio

I do this a lot when I'm watching TV. I lie on my back sometimes with my hands behind my head or to my side. I put both of my feet straight up together in the air (perpendicular to my body, I look like an L). Then I separate both legs to go to either side of my body as far as I can sometimes and I will slowly bring them back up to meet together.

I've been doing this for while, and I want to know the term for it to make sure others are doing it and that I'm doing it correctly.

Comment: Voting to close: [Do we identify equipment or exercises?](http://meta.fitness.stackexchange.com/q/395/3941).

Comment: These type of questions aren't particularly good for Stack Exchange.

Comment: There isn't really anything "Vague, broad, or half-remembered" about the description in the question, it is clear, concise, and easy to identify for anyone with knowledge in the field.  Wanting to learn about the correct way to perform a clearly described movement is certainly practical and answerable.

Comment: @Affe You should post that on meta. Even after Matt edited it, I still don't see how this question helps anyone besides the asker.

Answer (score 7):

The movement you're describing is *hip adduction*. You're exercising the [hip adductors](http://www.exrx.net/Muscles/Adductors.html), which are thigh muscles that pull your legs together.

I can't find an image of a bodyweight version of the exercise you're describing, but here is an image of the weighted exercise:

[image]

You can find out more about that exercise [here](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/HipAdductors/CBLyingHipAdduction.html).  There are some other examples in [this](http://www.exrx.net/Lists/ExList/ThighWt.html#anchor1943047) section of the thigh exercise page on exrx.  A google search for "hip adduction" or "hip adduction exercises" should give you a lot more direction on the movement if you would like to find out more.

Comment: I bet that if the question had included such an awesome GIF, there would be a lot less discussion. Nice find